# How can I create a single Visual Studio project that mixes C and C++ using CLR?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2008, clr, porting

I am working on porting code that builds on GCC on Unix to windows using Visual Studio 2008. I would like to create a single executable that does not depend on any dll(s) of my own creation and only built in ones to the Windows operating system.

My code includes zlib which itself includes C files which I can build and link fine into my Unix executable.

In my beginning attempts to build, the first error I hit is that the C code from zlib cannot be built with CLR since it is not C++.

I see some suggesting to break this out into a separate DLL which would be linked into my executable but I'd like to avoid the complexity of shared libraries if possible. (Perhaps this avoidance is even more complex?)

Is there a way to mix my C++ with the C code of zlib into a single executable with CLR?

My current build error is the following:

```
1>cl : Command line error D8045 : cannot compile C file '..\src\zlib-1.2.5\zutil.c' with the /clr option
```

Comment: You cannot create a program with /clr compiled object files that do not have a dependency.  Short from .NET having to be installed, you will also need to deploy the DLL version of the CRT.

Comment: You might like to have a look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0w2664k.

Comment: Also there does exist a win32 port for some zlib version: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/zlib.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change it to cpp to get it compiled by the C++ compiler (and fix any compile errors that introduces).  That may be more difficult than just using a shared library (dll).

Comment: C code should go through a C compiler. This will not be the case if you feed .cpp files to VC, it will use the C++ compiler then.

Comment: VC does provide a C compiler, which will be used to compile .c files. The issue is that this does not seem to work when specifying the CLR option. For details on this see my link above.

Comment: @alk I know there is a C compiler with Visual Studio.  /clr does not work with C.  He prefers not to have seperate library, so one possible workaround is to PORT the code to C++.  To start that process, he must change the file extension to .cpp.  I know that that invokes the C++ compiler, that is the point.  That is the goal of my answer.

Comment: Ok, I got your point ... Regarding complexity I wonder if porting this "standard" lib to C++ would make thing less complex.